# Call Method on event in xaml in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In WPF I call my Load method like so(using my MainViewModel in the DataContext):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

How can I do something similar in Xamarin Forms? Maybe on the Appearing event? Something like this, except I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
  <ContentPage.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="Appearing">

    </EventTrigger>
  </ContentPage.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `TriggerAction` for that.

**Xaml Usage**

```
  <ContentPage.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="Appearing">
      <local:DummyTriggerAction/>
    </EventTrigger>
  </ContentPage.Triggers>
```

**Trigger Action Class:**

```
public class DummyTriggerAction : TriggerAction<ContentPage>
{
    protected override void Invoke (ContentPage page)
    {
        //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there wasn't any code behind. otherwise I might as well just drop it in the Appearing event handler in code behind.